# Dúvida com alinhamento

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Suponhamos que a minha div de cor azul ao lado esquerdo fosse um menu, como eu faria pra colocar o conteúdo do site "AO LADO E NO CENTRO" ?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

div {
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
}

.test{
   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Testes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
    <div class="test">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis unde asperiores ipsa non perspiciatis culpa, vel temporibus, odio rerum excepturi ab ex repellat ipsum ad, soluta consequuntur optio odit obcaecati.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi o que seria exatamente, mas caso  for colocar uma `<div>` ao lado da outra você pode utilizar a propriedade `float: right/left`.

Exemplo:

HTML:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.menu {
  float: left; //Esquerda (Menu)
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
}

.test {
  float: right; //Direita (Conteúdo)
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Testes</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu"></div>
  <div class="test">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis unde asperiores ipsa non perspiciatis culpa, vel temporibus, odio rerum excepturi ab ex repellat ipsum ad, soluta consequuntur optio odit obcaecati.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**ou até mesmo a propriedade flex-box:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  //Flex-Box deve ser definido no elemento pai
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: #000;
}

.menu {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
}

.test {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Testes</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menu"></div>
    <div class="test">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis unde asperiores ipsa non perspiciatis culpa, vel temporibus, odio rerum excepturi ab ex repellat ipsum ad, soluta consequuntur optio odit obcaecati.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```